# Can I send images + boundingboxes(as features) to an LSTM? How?

Tags: deep-learning, classification, lstm, computer-vision, object-detection

I have previously trained a YOLO v4 object detection model and I am looking to leverage the results(Bboxes) of this model and create another model to recognize/classify accidents in CCTV footage/video(hopefully in real-time).

I am thinking of sending the bounding boxes from object detection results, as features along with the video frames to my Accident Detection model, but I'm really not sure if this is possible and how I can achieve this as I can't even find examples of people doing this on this internet.

I know i can crop objects and send to lstm but that way model wont get environment features.
Then again, just passing coordinates of the image doesn't tell the model that those are indeed coordinates of area of interest in the image... so it has me confused..

Any help is appreciated, It is a time-sensitive academic task. I understand it takes time to build a proper project with good accuracy, for now my goal is just to have a working prototype asap.